# How to remove everything from a row except pattern

Tags: r

I have a dataframe that contains one column separated by `;` like this

```
AB00001;09843;AB00002;GD00001
AB84375;34
AB84375;AB84375
74859375;AB001;4455;FG3455
```

What I want is remove everything except the codes that starts with AB....

```
AB00001;AB00002
AB84375
AB84375;AB84375
AB001
```

I've tried to separate them with `separate()`, but I don´t know how to continue. Any suggestions?

Comment: another one `gsub(';$', '', gsub('(AB[^;]+;?)|.', '\\1', x))`

Answer (score 4):

If your data frame is called `df` and your column is called `V1`, you could try:

```
sapply(strsplit(df$V1, ";"), function(x) paste(grep("^AB", x, value = TRUE), collapse = ";"))
#> [1] "AB00001;AB00002" "AB84375"         "AB84375;AB84375" "AB001"
```

This splits at all the semicolons then matches all strings starting with "AB", then joins them back together with semicolons.

Comment: Beat me to it, I was about to post this exact answer. I'll just add the example data `structure(list(data = c("AB00001;09843;AB00002;GD00001", "AB84375;34", 
"AB84375;AB84375", "74859375;AB001;4455;FG3455")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-4L))`

Comment: It's a bit of a "fastest gun in the West" type question @DanielO. The type akrun normally answers before the rest of us can blink!

Answer (score 2):

I thought of using `stringr` and Daniel O's data:

```r
df %>%
  mutate(data = str_extract_all(data, "AB\\w+"))
```

which gives us

```r
              data
1 AB00001, AB00002
2          AB84375
3 AB84375, AB84375
4            AB001
```

Answer (score 2):

**1) Base R** Assuming `DF` shown reproducibly in the Note at the end we prefix each line with a semicolon and then use the `gsub` with the pattern shown and finally remove the semicolon we added.  No packages are used.

```
transform(DF, V1 = sub("^;", "", gsub("(;AB\\d+)|;[^;]*", "\\1", paste0(";", V1))))
```

giving:

```
               V1
1 AB00001;AB00002
2         AB84375
3 AB84375;AB84375
4           AB001
```

**2) dplyr/tidyr** This one is longer than the others in this answer but it is straight forward and has no complex regular expressions.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

DF %>%
  mutate(id = 1:n()) %>%
  separate_rows(V1, sep = ";") %>%
  filter(substr(V1, 1, 2) == "AB") %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarize(V1 = paste(V1, collapse = ";")) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-id)
```

giving:

```
# A tibble: 4 x 1
  V1             
  <chr>          
1 AB00001;AB00002
2 AB84375        
3 AB84375;AB84375
4 AB001
```

**3) gsubfn**  Replace codes that do not start with AB with an empty string and then remove redundant semicolons from what is left.

```
library(gsubfn)
transform(DF, V1 = gsub("^;|;$", "", gsub(";+", ";", 
  gsubfn("[^;]*", ~ if (substr(x, 1, 2) == "AB") x else "", V1))))
```

giving:

```
               V1
1 AB00001;AB00002
2         AB84375
3 AB84375;AB84375
4           AB001
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "AB00001;09843;AB00002;GD00001
AB84375;34
AB84375;AB84375
74859375;AB001;4455;FG3455"
DF <- read.table(text = Lines, as.is = TRUE, strip.white = TRUE)
```